# (PDE) Find the plane features of the following equations. a) $3u_x - 4u_y = x^2$ b) $x^2u_x + y^2u_y = x^3$...

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

$x = \alpha(s), y = \beta(s)$

a)$\alpha'(s) = 3 \to \alpha = \int 3 ds = 3s + c_1$

$ \beta'(s)=-4 \to \alpha = (7-4)s + c_1 = (7 + \beta')s + c_1$

b)$\alpha'(s) = \alpha(s)^2 \to \alpha'(s)\beta(s)^2 = \alpha(s)^2\beta(s)^2$ (i)

$\beta'(s)=\beta(s)^2 \to \beta'(s)\alpha(s)^2 = \beta(s)^2\alpha(s)^2$ (ii)

(i)-(ii) = $\alpha'(s)\beta(s)^2 - \beta'(s)\alpha(s)^2 = 0$

I'm stuck. I need to find the equation of the line ax+by + c = 0. But I can't relate $x, y$ without the $s$.

EX from the book.

$2yu_x + u_y = (2y^2 + x)sin(2xy) \in \mathbb R$

$\alpha'(s) = 2\beta(s)$

$\beta'(s) = 1 \to \int \beta'(s) ds = \int 1 ds = \beta(s) = s + c_1$

$\int \alpha'(s) ds = \int 2(\beta) ds = \int 2s ds + \int 2c_1 ds$

$\alpha(s) = s^2 + 2sc_1 + c_2 = (s + c_1)^2 + c_2 - c_1^2$

$x = y^2 + c$

Thanks.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: In your question you use not defined symbols $s,\alpha,\beta$. What are they?

Comment: @JJacquelin If C is a flat characteristic curve parameterized by ($\alpha(s), \beta(s)$), the PDE along $C$ becomes: $a(\alpha(s), \beta(s)) u_x((\alpha(s), \beta(s)) + b(\alpha(s), \beta(s))u_y(\alpha(s), \beta(s)) = c(\alpha( s), \beta(s)) $

Comment: @JJacquelin I don't understand $u(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{y}+F(3y+4x)\quad$, u(x,y)=\frac12 x^2+f(\frac{ 1}{y}-\frac{1}{x})\quad$.

Comment: There was a typo. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\boxed{3u_x-4u_y=x^2}$$
The Charpit_Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{3}=\frac{dy}{-4}=\frac{du}{x^2}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{3}=\frac{dy}{-4}$ :
$$4x+3y=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{3}=\frac{du}{x^2}$ :
$$u-\frac19 x^3=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE (without taking account of boundary condition) on form of implicite equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u-\frac19 x^3=F(4x+3y)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac19 x^3+F(4x+3y)}$$
Since no boundary condition is specified in the wording of the question the function $F$ cannot be determined. This means that they are infinity many solutions because infinity many functions $F$ can be considerted.

Checking of the above result :

$u_x=\frac13 x^2+4\frac{dF}{dX}$ with $X=4x+3y$.

$u_y=3\frac{dF}{dX}$ with $X=4x+3y$.

$3u_x-4u_y=3\left(\frac13 x^2+4\frac{dF(X)}{dX}\right)-4\left(3\frac{dF(X)}{dX}\right)$

After simplification : $3u_x-4u_y=x^2$. Thus the PDE is satisfied any $F$.

SECOND PROBLEM :

$$\boxed{x^2u_x + y^2u_y = x^3}$$

The Charpit_Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{du}{x^3}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}$ :
$$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{du}{x^3}$ :
$$u-\frac12 x^2=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE (without taking account of boundary condition) on form of implicite equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u-\frac12 x^2=F(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x})$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=\frac12 x^2+F(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x})}$$
Since no boundary condition is specified in the wording of the question the function $F$ cannot be determined. This means that they are infinity many solutions because infinity many functions $F$ can be considerted.

Checking of the above result :

$u_x=x+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dF}{dX}$ with $X=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}$.

$u_y=-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dF}{dX}$ with $X=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}$.

$x^2u_x + y^2u_y =x^2\left(x+\frac{1}{x^2}\frac{dF}{dX}\right)+y^2\left(-\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dF}{dX}\right)$

After simplification : $x^2u_x + y^2u_y=x^3$. Thus the PDE is satisfied any $F$.